# javascript/jquery: Iterative called function; wait till the previous call is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've some problem with a library calling a function on each item. I've to check the state for this item via an ajax request and don't want to call one request per item, but get a range of item states. 
Because these items are dates I can get some range pretty easy - that's the good part :)

So to to give some code ...

```
var itemStates = {};

var libraryObj = {
    itemCallback: function(item) {
        return checkState(item);
    }
}

function checkState(item) {
    if(!itemStates.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        $.get('...', function(result) {
            $.extend(true, itemStates, result);
        });
    }

    return itemStates[item];
}
```

The library is now calling library.itemCallback() on each item, but I want to wait for the request made in checkState() before calling checkState() again (because the chance is extremly high the next items' state was allready requested within the previous request.

I read about the defer and wait(), then() and so on, but couldn't really get an idea how to implement this.

Many thanks to everybody who could help me with this :)

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look on that and try to understand it ;)

Comment: don't cache the results, cache the promises, and continue with them. `function checkState(item) {
 return item in itemStates? itemStates[item]: (itemStates[item] = $.get('...'));
}` now it doesn't matter how often `checkState` is called for the same item, it will always return the same promise. but you'll have to adapt the code that utilizes `itemCallback` that it now get's a Promise instead of the value. (sidenote: depending on wich version of jQuery you use, jQuerys implementation of Deferred sucks; you might want to use a better implementation, like [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `jQuery.Deferred` or `Javascript Promise`. In the following code, `itemCallback()` will wait for previous calls to finish before calling `checkState()`.

```
var queue = [];
var itemStates = {};

var libraryObj = {
  itemCallback: function(item) {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    $.when.apply(null, queue)
      .then(function() {
        return checkState(item);
      })
      .then(function(result) {
        def.resolve(result);
      });
    queue.push(def.promise());
    return def.promise();
  }
}

function checkState(item) {
  var def = $.Deferred();
  if (!itemStates.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    $.get('...', function(result) {
      $.extend(true, itemStates, result);
      def.resolve(itemStates[item]);
    });
  } else
    def.resolve(itemStates[item]);
  return def.promise();
}

//these will execute in order, waiting for the previous call
libraryObj.itemCallback(1).done(function(r) { console.log(r); });
libraryObj.itemCallback(2).done(function(r) { console.log(r); });
libraryObj.itemCallback(3).done(function(r) { console.log(r); });
libraryObj.itemCallback(4).done(function(r) { console.log(r); });
libraryObj.itemCallback(5).done(function(r) { console.log(r); });
```

---

Same example built with `Javascript Promises`

```
var queue = [];
var itemStates = {};

var libraryObj = {
  itemCallback: function(item) {
    var promise = new Promise(resolve => {
      Promise.all(queue)
        .then(() => checkState(item))
        .then((result) => resolve(result));
    });
    queue.push(promise);
    return promise;
  }
}

function checkState(item) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (item in itemStates)
      resolve(itemStates[item]);
    else {
      $.get('...', function(result) {
        $.extend(true, itemStates, result);
        resolve(itemStates[item]);
      });
    }
  });
}

//these will execute in order, waiting for the previous call
libraryObj.itemCallback(1).then(function(r) { console.log(r); });
libraryObj.itemCallback(2).then(function(r) { console.log(r); });
libraryObj.itemCallback(3).then(function(r) { console.log(r); });
libraryObj.itemCallback(4).then(function(r) { console.log(r); });
libraryObj.itemCallback(5).then(function(r) { console.log(r); });
```

Answer (score 0):

simplest and dirty way of taking control over the library is to override their methods

But I don't really know core problem here so other hints are below

If you have the control over the checkState then just collect your data and change your controller on the server side to work with arrays that's it

and if you don't know when the next checkState will be called to count your collection and make the request use setTimeout to check collection after some time or setIterval to check it continuously

if you don't want to get same item multiple times then store your checked items in some variable like `alreadyChecked` and before making request search for this item in `alreadyChecked`

to be notified when some library is using your item use [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty),
and then collect your items.
When you will have enough items collected then you can make the request,
but when you will not have enought items then use setTimeout and wait for some time. If nothing changes, then it means that library finishes the iteration for now and you can make the request with items that left of.

```
let collection=[];// collection for request
let _items={};// real items for you when you don't want to perfrom actions while getting values
let itemStates={};// items for library
let timeoutId;
//instead of itemStates[someState]=someValue; use
function setItem(someState,someValue){

  Object.defineProperty(itemStates, someState, { get: function () {
    if(typeof timeoutId=="number")clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    //here you can add someState to the collection for request
    collection.push(_items[someState]);
    if(collection.length>=10){
      makeRequest();
    }else{
      timeoutId=setTimeout(()=>{...checkCollectionAndMakeRequest...},someTime);
    }
    return someValue;
  } });
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that I have no control about how checkState() is called, and when the library have been gone through all items ...

Comment: maybe use getter/setter and if some lib will get your item you can react accordingly. but if you don't have control over checkState so how you want to replace it functionality?

Comment: Well the "how" was maybe a little bit misleading ...
the word "when" would be better

Comment: I've changed my answer but I really don't know exactly where is the problem. When you can modify code which make the request there is no problem, but if you can make something after the request then you have to override the `jquery get function` to cancel the query. but I don't really know what is the problem

Comment: @neuronet, the problem is caused by the async nature of the ajax request inside checkState. OP wants to make sure previous calls to itemCallback/checkState are finished before a new one gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

> The library is now calling library.itemCallback() on each item, but I want to wait for the request made in checkState() before calling checkState() again (because the chance is extremely high the next items' state was already requested within the previous request.

One thing I can think of doing is making some caching function, depending on the last time the function was called return the previous value or make a new request

```
var cached = function(self, cachingTime, fn){
    var paramMap = {};

    return function( ) {

        var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        var parameters = JSON.stringify(arr);
        var returning;

        if(!paramMap[parameters]){

           returning = fn.apply(self,arr);       
           paramMap[parameters]={timeCalled: new Date(), value:returning};

        } else  {

           var diffMs = Math.abs(paramMap[parameters].timeCalled - new Date());
           var diffMins = ( diffMs / 1000 ) / 60;

           if(diffMins > cachingTime){

               returning = fn.apply(self,arr);       
               paramMap[parameters] = {timeCalled: new Date(), value:returning};    

           } else {

              returning = paramMap[parameters].value;

            }

        }

        return returning;
    }
}
```

Then you'd wrap the ajax call into the function you've made

```
var fn = cached(null, 1 , function(item){
        return $.get('...', function(result) {
            $.extend(true, itemStates, result);
        });
});
```

Executing the new function would get you the last promise called for those parameters within the last request made at the last minute with those parameters or make a new request